# How does MySQL pick which slave to send query to?

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

Say I have a JDBC url like this...

```
jdbc:mysql:replication://master,slave1,slave2,slave3/<database>
```

How does MySQL decide which slave to send a read request to?
Is it round robin or does it do anything a bit more clever such as checking which has the lowest latency (what if my slaves were distributed in data centers in different regions)?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-master-slave-replication-connection.html says:

> An application signals that it wants a transaction to be read-only by calling Connection.setReadOnly(true). The replication-aware connection will use one of the slave connections, which are load-balanced per slave host **using a round-robin scheme.**

(emphasis mine)